# what does soft topology mean?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have just read the concept "soft topology". I need to understand its characteristics and possible applications.
Is there any simple reference introducing this concept and another reference for its applications.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more context about your background, or why you're searching, and why your search has not been satisfying so far? For instance a quick google search suggests the term might have been introduced in a paper from 2011/2012 that you could read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question lacks a great deal of context. As Mark suggests in the comments, a google search reveals the following two papers:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122111004044

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122111000927